# How to show a scrollbar for a negative translated element (with CSS transform)

Tags: html, css

I would like to show an image with pan and zoom. I use [panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom) which leverage CSS `transform` with `scale` and `transform`. In some case, I'd like to show the user where the image is actually zoomed, using scrollbars.

Therefore, I applied `overflow: auto;` to the parent element. However, it seems that scrollbars are only shown when the transformed image is on the right (with positive translation), and not and the left (with negative values).

See the following simple example. On the first `div`, I'd like to show scrollbars as in the second one (except for position).

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper.left>img {
  transform: translate(-20px, -20px);
}

.wrapper.right>img {
  transform: translate(270px, 170px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Face-smile.svg/48px-Face-smile.svg.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper right">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/79/Face-smile.svg/48px-Face-smile.svg.png" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Transforms remove elements from their stacking context. In short, you need to make the element's content that's still part of the stacking order larger than the overflow container.

So you would need to add a negative margin to the container element equal the transform amount and then padding to bring the normal (non-translated) content back.

All that said. **You actually CANNOT scroll up or left in a browser past zero.** So you have to trick the scroll into starting at a positive non-zero number. Eg: scroll bar starts as if the content is scrolled to 100%.

Comment: OK, thanks for the precision in bold letters. This seems a bit weird, but then I'll have to think about another UI for my purpose.

Comment: You can use the `@use-gesture/react` library instead which provides more flexibility and control over the transformed element. The way I solve this was to listen on the `onDrag` event and once the dragged element enters a negative position, I added a `padding-top` style to the transformed parent element. Note: The value of the padding-top is equivalent to the 'y` value of the transform3d style property.

Comment: absolute right on answer which avoids using  overflow hidden on the body. I love it